# 2.91 viewport lag after certain amount of time

Tags: 3d-view, performance

When I open Blender it runs perfectly smooth, but after a while it begins to lag. I close and open the same file and it runs smoothly again, until about fifteen or twenty minutes pass and it starts lagging again. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your OS tell you the memory available to you. RAM ..GPU RAM?  Can you provide that info?  At the Smooth behavior and Lag behavior.  Elapsed Time? Do you feel you have many other applications open .. such as a browser?  Which applications are consuming the most memory?  Would you like to state some machine specs .. RAM ? GPU?

Comment: I have 32 gb RAM, 25% of which is used. My graphics processor is nothing special: Intel HD graphics 530. Even if Blender is the only thing open it still has this problem after about twenty to thirty minutes.